# Why images and text with links keep moving on hover

Tags: html, css

All my image and text containing links happened to be moving on mouse over. I checked on my CSS and tried few solution like below it still not working:

1. Add padding
2. Add position:relative

My page on is http://www.ttc.edu.my/welcome

```css
.highlight-box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.highlight-box h3 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box h1 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box h6 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box p {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight-box col-md-6">
  <div class="highlight-box">
    <span><a href="http://www.ttc.edu.my/course/engineering"><br /><img src="Untitled-1_01.jpg"></p>
<div class="centered">
<h3>Skills Diplomas</h3>
<p>Click for More Info</p>
<p></a></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Comment: Question is unclear. What do you need to do here? Try remove </p> tag after <img> tag. There is another <p> down there witch does not closed

Comment: Thanks, just noticed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like issue is related to border property of . So try this.

```
#megaMenu #megaST li.menu-item-depth-0 a.link-depth-0:link, #megaMenu li.menu-item-depth-0 a.link-depth-0:visited{
           padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
           border: none;
    }
```

Comment: thanks! it works on my menu no more issue by adding border:none;  I also add border:none !important to a {  for my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your HTML has **horribly** invalid markup. Correcting it resolves the issue. Remember to validate your markup with the **[W3C validation service](https://validator.w3.org)**.

Here's the markup I **believe** you're looking for
(with a black background added to show the white font):

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.highlight-box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.highlight-box h3 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box h1 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box h6 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box p {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight-box a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight-box col-md-6">
  <div class="highlight-box">
    <img src="Untitled-1_01.jpg" />
    <div class="centered">
      <h3>Skills Diplomas</h3>
      <p>
        <a href="http://www.ttc.edu.my/course/engineering">Click for More Info</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You're additionally probably looking for `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` on `.centered` so that the elements are actually in the center of the page (and not off it).

Hope this helps! :)